# Find the radius of the circle

Tags: geometry

Consider this question: There are two Circles one with center C and other with center O, if the both the circles externally touch each other at one point and are tangent to the x axis, find out the radius of the circle that is tangent to both of them and also to the x axis. [given radius of big circle R1 and small circle R2]

[image]

Now I know there is a way to do using pure geometry(idk what it's called), but I want the solution to be using cartesian geometry

My attempt:

I took circle $S_1$ as $(y-R_1)^2 + x^2 - (R_1)^2 = 0$
$S_2$ as $(y-R_2)^2 + (x-2\sqrt{R1R2})^2 - (R_2)^2 = 0$

then since $S_3$ is tangent to Y axis. ($S_3$ is tangent to $y = 0$ at ($b,0$))

$\implies (x-b)^2 + y^2 + \lambda y = 0 \\ 
$

then I tried equating sum of radii and distance of cordinates by -

$(\lvert - \frac{\lambda}{2}\rvert + R_1)^2 = (b)^2 + (\lvert - \frac{\lambda}{2}\rvert - R_1)^2 \\
$

$(\lvert - \frac{\lambda}{2}\rvert + R_2)^2 = (b-2\sqrt{R1R2})^2 + (\lvert - \frac{\lambda}{2}\rvert - R_2)^2 \\
$

Then finding $\lambda$ and final radius becomes $\lvert \frac{\lambda}{2}\rvert $  But It's too messy, can someone post a more elegant solution to this using cartesian geometry only. Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem#Special_cases) can help

Comment: You have a triangle with sides $R+x$, $r+x$ and $R+r$ where $x$ is the unknown radius and $R,r$ are the radii of the other two circles.

Answer (score 3):

If $DG=r$, the same way ad you got the position of the circle with radius $R_2$ you can write $$AG^2=(R_1+r)^2-(R_1-r)^2=4R_1r\\GF^2=(R_2+r)^2-(R_2-r)^2=4R_2r$$
You also know that $$AF^2=(R_1+R_2)^2-(R_1-R_2)^2=4R_1R_2$$
So $$\sqrt{R_1R_2}=\sqrt r\left(\sqrt{R_1}+\sqrt{R_2}\right)$$
Therefore $$r=\frac{R_1R_2}{\left(\sqrt{R_1}+\sqrt{R_2}\right)^2}$$